# Create Android Artifact based on branch name in Azure DevOps

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Currently have a project on ADO.
When we make a release branch it will create an artifact (gradle dependency), and update the min/major version of it.
I want to create a new type of artifact, that can be used for testing integrations.

For example, say I have a branch, '**Test-Branch-1**', I want to be able to create and publish an artifact, something like '**com.test.myproject:Test-Branch-1**', which will be built from the branch specified. This will make it easy for us to test fixes and apply them to integrating applications.

I don't have much experience in ADO and pipelines etc, so I am not sure how I would best do this.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

edit. Adding the actual pipeline

```
trigger: 
  branches: 
    include: 
      - main 
      - releases/*
  paths:
    exclude:
      - docs/*.md
      - README.md

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-22.04

workspace:
  clean: all

variables:
  - group: my-group
  - name: is_release
    value: $[contains(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'releases/')]
  - name: release_version
    value: $[replace(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/', '')]
  - name: displayName
    value: $[replace(replace('True', eq(variables['is_release'], 'True'), 'Build, Test & Publish'), 'True', 'Build & Test')]
  - name: tasks
    value: $[replace(replace('True', eq(variables['is_release'], 'True'), 'clean ktlintCheck assemble test publish'), 'True', 'clean ktlintCheck assemble test')]

steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Bump Build Version Tag
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['is_release'], 'true'))
    inputs:
      filePath: 'bump_git_tag.sh'
      arguments: $(release_version)
  - task: Gradle@3
    displayName: $(displayName)
    env:
      ADO_PAT: $(ADO_PAT)
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      tasks: $(tasks)
      codeCoverageToolOption: ''
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      checkStyleRunAnalysis: true
      findBugsRunAnalysis: false
      pmdRunAnalysis: true
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Push Bumped Build Version Tag'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['is_release'], 'true'))
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        git config --global user.email "myname@gmail.com"
        git config --global user.name "myname.secondname"
        git push origin $(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
```

Comment: Use the `Build.SourceBranchName` variable to retrieve the name of the branch during your pipeline's run. If you want something beyond that, you'll need to share your pipeline.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks, that's useful. How would I select what branch I want to build from? And do I need a separate artifact feed to hold all these artifacts or could it mix with the actual release version feed?

Comment: You can choose the branch when you queue the build. Whether you use the same artifact feed or a separate one is a matter of preference.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks! It's good to know it's possible. Can you leave an answer that's a bit more in-depth and I can select it as the answer then? I also updated my OP with the current pipeline I have. As per my OP, I want to have main be snapshot, releases update the version, which it does with the bash script, and then if i specify another branch, i want it to create an artifact with the branch name and no version. Not sure if its possible or how I can add that to a separate artifact feed. If you could provide some info on this it would be awesome!